# How to create radio streaming in Android

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I try to integrate a radio streaming in my app but it don't work and i don't know why.
This is the link of my web radio : https://www.radioking.com/widgets/player/player.php?id=480&c=%23f39c12&ii=&p=1&pp=1&i=1&eq=1&po=1&t=1&a=1&f=big

Can you help me ?
This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioStreamBtn);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

                    if (initialStage) {
                        new Player().execute("https://www.radioking.com/widgets/player/player.php?id=480&c=%23f39c12&ii=&p=1&pp=1&i=1&eq=1&po=1&t=1&a=1&f=big");
                    } else {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }

                    playPause = true;

                } else {
                    btn.setText("Launch Streaming");

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }

                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        initialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        btn.setText("Launch Streaming");
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            initialStage = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in the title, it's considered the same as YELLING at us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use exoplayer2 but you need to use the direct link to the stream and not the radio directory php link. Good luck.

Comment: Please do not copy someone else's answer. @Reena had already answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try ExoPlayer which supports features like Dynamic adaptive streaming over HTTP (DASH), SmoothStreaming and Common Encryption, which are not supported by MediaPlayer. It's designed to be easy to customize and extend.
Here is link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html